# Animated movie with dwarves who don't have hearts

Tags: story-identification, movie, dwarves, animation

I watched this animated movie when I was a kid, between 1998 and 2015.

In the movie there was a race of dwarves and it was known that they didn't have hearts. When emptiness started to take over and turning things into stone, a group of I think five dwarves decided to go on a quest for a magical heart that can turn things back to normal. A young elf tags along on their journey. During the ending the heart goes into one of the dwarves chest and makes him look more feminine, the others think it's a curse so they try to kill the heart. The elf jumps in front of the arrow and gets hit; after that he falls into a lake, I think. In the end the one to have the heart is the elf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! For some help improving this question, see [this awesome guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999)! For a start, **about when was this that you saw the movie?** We don't know when you were a kid, it could have been 1837 or 2016.

Comment: @Stormblessed Lol, 1837?

Comment: Quest for a heart; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zb4e2BZxf8?

Comment: @Valorum [yup](https://vimeo.com/110613395)

Answer (score 7):

Could this be [Quest for a Heart](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796232/)?

It's got dwarves (actually short trolls), an elf and plenty of questing. And hearts.

> When the most mischievous resident of Rolli Village befriends a beautiful elf girl, the hopelessly mismatched pair embarks on a magical adventure to save the Forest of Elves by traveling to the Land of Winter and recovering the mythical magical heart in this animated tale of wonder for the entire family.

Comment: Ah, and turning to stone makes more sense, since apparently they are trolls (https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Millie_(Quest_for_a_Heart)). "Millie is a spunky elf girl who accompanies Rolli the troll on a quest to find a magical heart that will save the trolls' village from being turned to stone. She stands for everything the trolls despise but, armed with her trusty bow and arrow, Millie proves herself a worthy ally."